# Is there any way to compare emojis with discordpy?

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a selection screen with two options (two reactions) which the user can react to, and the bot will now what reaction did the user chose

I've tried comparing
reaction != "" or reaction != "✋"
Also tried:
reaction != u"\U0001F44C" or reaction != u"\u270B"
using the unicode.
Also tried the same code with reaction.emoji, str(reaction / reaction.emoji).
Also tried comparing the id of the emojis but reaction.emoji.id raise an exception saying that reaction.emoji is a str and strings doesn't have id
(because idk why it returns a str instead of a emoji object)
I've read the docs and it says it supports != operations but I don't know what to compare

```
@bot.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction,user):
     print(reaction) #It prints the two emojis on my console ( and ✋)
     if user.bot:
        print('I am a bot')
        return
     if reaction != "" or reaction != "✋":
        print('Did not found the emoji')
        return
     else:
        print('Found the emoji')
#And then some code which will decide if the user that reacted is valid and what to do with it
    

#The embed the user have to react to if this helps
embed = discord.Embed(title = 'VS',color=0x00fff5)
        embed.set_author(name = message.author.name,icon_url=message.author.avatar_url)
        embed.set_footer(text = message.mentions[0].name , icon_url = mensaje.mentions[0].avatar_url)
        response = await message.channel.send(embed = embed)
        await response.add_reaction("") #OK emoji
        await response.add_reaction("✋") #STOP emoji
```

I expect the bot to recognize the emojis but don't know how.

Comment: The docs [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=emoji#discord.Client.wait_for) definitely suggest it is `str(reaction.emoji) == ''` as you tried. I am wondering if this line `if str(reaction.emoji) != "" or str(reaction.emoji) != "✋":` can ever evaluate to `False` though. Could you try something simpler like 
`if str(reaction.emoji) == "":
    print("OK reaction found")`

Comment: You should almost certainly be using [`Client.wait_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for) instead of `on_reaction_add`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

1. switch `or` for `and`
2. use `str(reaction.emoji)` (see example in the discordpy [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=emoji#discord.Client.wait_for))

**Explanation:**

[De Morgan's Laws](https://brilliant.org/wiki/de-morgans-laws/) would say that

```
if str(reaction.emoji) != "" or str(reaction.emoji) != "✋":
```

is the same as writing

```
if not (str(reaction.emoji) ==  "" and str(reaction.emoji) == "✋"):
```

and since the reaction cannot be both an OK *and* a STOP at the same time, that `if` statement always comes back `True` and "Did not find the emoji" is always printed.

Something like

```
     if str(reaction.emoji) != "" and str(reaction.emoji) != "✋":
        print('Did not found the emoji')
        return
     else:
        print('Found the emoji')
```

would work.

EDIT: A slightly more readable solution IMHO would be to check for the presence of the emoji in a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets).

```
     if str(reaction.emoji) not in { "", "✋"}:
        print('Did not find the emoji')
        return
     else:
        print('Found the emoji')
```